# Display a decimal column, but as a whole number whenever possible

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a column like this

```
value
50.67
60.004
20.0
30.2
14.0
```

I need it to be displayed like this

```
value
50.67
60.004
20
30.2
14
```

So numbers `20.0` and `14.0` are displayed as `20` and `14`, because they are essentially whole numbers.

Is it possible to achieve?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to achieve?.

From an SQLite perspective you do not need to do anything; as the following demonstrates:-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (v1 REAL, v2 TEXT, v3 NUMERIC, v4 blah_blah);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES 
    (50.67,50.67,50.67,50.67),
    (60.004,60.004,60.004,60.004),
    (20.0,20.0,20.0,20.0),
    (30.2,30.2,30.2,30.2),
    (14.0,14.0,14.0,14.0),
    ('20.0','20.0','20.0','20.0');
SELECT * FROM mytable;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable;
```

Which results in :-

[image]

- for all typical column types (except type blah_blah which will resolve to a column affinity of NUMERIC).

**However** how you finally retrieve the results from the output (e.g. android's getString will get as above, BUT getDouble will get as a double with whatever the default precision is for  that function) can/does matter.

**So you probably want to retrieve the value as if it were a String.**

- **The above assumes that the values stored will never be NULL. Handling nulls can be handled using the `coalesce` or `ifnull` SQLite built-in functions** - see https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#coalesce and/or https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#ifnull
- You may wish to refer to https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#type_affinity (and perhaps the entire document) for a more detailed explanation.

You could use something like:-

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (v1 - CAST(CAST(v1 AS INTEGER) AS REAL)) = 0 THEN CAST(v1 AS INTEGER) ELSE v1 END AS v1 FROM mytable;
```

- note just the one column shown

e.g. :-

[image]

Which replicates the what SQLite actually does, but then you are still at the mercy of the function(s) that retrieve the data from the resultant output (again retrieval as a String type should get the output as is).

A word of warning re precision. If we take the crux of the second SQL based solution you may have to consider the full precision/inaccuracy/inability to store exact decimal values. The following demonstrates what NOT TO DO:-

```
SELECT CAST(v1 AS INTEGER)|| CASE WHEN (v1 % 1)  > 0 THEN '.'||v1 % 1 ELSE '' END, (v1 - CAST(CAST(v1 AS INTEGER) AS REAL)) AS warning  FROM mytable;
```

This results in the two parts (integer part and mantissa) :-

- [image]
- ***so trying to build a string from the 2 parts will often, unless  a more complicated process is used, may result in unexpected results.***

Answer (score 1):

This is really easy to do with the [`format()` function](https://sqlite.org/printf.html)'s `%g` format specifier:

```sql
sqlite> create table foo(value REAL);
sqlite> insert into foo values (50.67), (60.004), (20.0), (30.2), (14.0);
sqlite> select * from foo;
50.67
60.004
20.0
30.2
14.0
sqlite> select format('%g', value) from foo;
50.67
60.004
20
30.2
14
sqlite>
```

The caveat is that really big numbers, or numbers closer to 0 will end up being displayed using scientific notation. Not an issue with the example numbers here, though.